# Assert_select with text and children elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

So if this is in my view

```
<div class='foo'>Some text: <strong>strong text</strong></div>
```

I want to write a test around it using rails minitest.

so far I have:

```
assert_select '.foo' do 
  assert 'Some text:', 1
  assert_select 'strong', 'strong text', 1
end
```

And this works, however I want to check it altogether like:

```
assert_select '.foo', 'Some text: <strong>strong text</strong>', 1
```

Answer (score 2):

> To perform more than one equality tests, use a hash with the following
>   keys:
>
> - :text - Narrow the selection to elements that have this text value (string or regexp).
> - :html - Narrow the selection to elements that have this HTML content (string or regexp).
>
> https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions.html#method-i-assert_select

```
assert_select '.foo', html: 'Some text: <strong>strong text</strong>'
```